# WPF/C# DataTemplate changes Layout cause of icon

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I've written an `DataTemplate` for a WPF `ListBox`. But when I use 2 specific icons of my 3, the layout changes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMp7F.png

That's my `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Name="tbID" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                   <Image Height="25" Width="25" Source="{Binding img_src}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
                   <StackPanel Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" >
                       <TextBlock  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="11" Text="{Binding errorOriginal}"/>
                       <TextBlock  FontSize="10" Text="{Binding errorGerman}" />
                       <!-- Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"   -->
                   </StackPanel>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And this is my class:

```
public class compEntry
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string img_src { get; set; }
    public string errorOriginal { get; set; }
    public string errorGerman { get; set; }
}
```

Please tell me about my mistake.

//EDIT:
When I fill my Class manually (no strings) it works:

```
compList.Add(new compEntry() { id = i, img_src = img, errorOriginal = errText[i], errorGerman = trans }); // not working
compList.Add(new compEntry() { id = i, img_src = img, errorOriginal = "test", errorGerman = "test" });//working
```

//EDIT2:
Found the solution. Just trimming the strings:

```
 compList.Add(new compEntry() { id = i, img_src = img, errorOriginal = errText[i].Trim(), errorGerman = trans.Trim() });
```

Comment: Are all the images the same size?

Comment: Yes. They all have the size of 26x26. Even if i remove the image of my template, the layout mistake is still there

Comment: This seems kind of bizarre... the only possible explanation I can think of is that the error text has newline characters at the end.

Comment: Yeah. That's the solution. I've just trimmed them and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark this question as answered. I just read the whole thing to find out you already figured it out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Just trimming the strings:

```
compList.Add(new compEntry() { id = i, img_src = img, errorOriginal = errText[i].Trim(), errorGerman = trans.Trim() });
```